# Como imprimir o saldo em ordem crescente e calcular juros no python

Tags: python-3.x

Pessoal eu tenho um trabalho na qual eu devo reproduzir a seguinte tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu não tenho muito conhecimento em python e estou dando o meu melhor para tentar reproduzir ela. Mas estou conseguindo retornar somente desta maneira.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. O mês eu não sei como colocar na ordem crescente e nem retirar o 0
   no final.
2. Do saldo inicial ao saldo final eu consigo imprimir, o problema é
   que ele imprime até 0.
3. Não sei a lógica da prestação.
4. Não sei a lógica dos Juros (quadro verde).
5. Não sei a lógica dos juros mensais (quadro vermelho).
6. Não sei como imprimir o saldo final (que nesse caso é o inverso do
   saldo inicial).

Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
# enconding: utf-8
########################################
# VERSÃO UTILIZADA: Python 3.6.5       #
# DISCIPLINA: Introdução à Programação #
########################################

#########################################
# Informações de entrada dada pelo user #
#########################################

import os

valor_financiamento = float ( input ("1. Informe o valor a ser financiado: "))
os.system("cls")
prazo = int ( input ("2. Informe o prazo de quitação do financiamento (em meses): "))
os.system("cls")
taxa_juros_anual = float (input ("3. Informe a taxa de juros anual (em %): "))
os.system("cls")


# Início da programação e cálculo
# USO DO SISTEMA SAC       


# O cálculo da amortização é realizado pelo valor do financiamento divido pela quantidade de meses
amortizacao = valor_financiamento / prazo

saldo_devedor = valor_financiamento - amortizacao

taxa_mensal = taxa_juros_anual / prazo

juros_mes = (taxa_juros_anual - 1 + 1 ) * amortizacao * taxa_mensal

prestacao = amortizacao + juros_mes
#valor_financiamento = str (valor_financiamento).replace('.',',')


#print ("AMORTIZAÇÃO: R$ %.2f" % amortizacao)
#print ("VALOR DO FINANCIAMENTO: R$ %.2f\n\n" % valor_financiamento)
print ("\t FINANCIAMENTO = R$ %.2f \t MESES: %i meses \t TAXA: %i%% ano (%.f%)" % (valor_financiamento, prazo, taxa_juros_anual, juros_mes))
print ("\t","-"*80,"\n")
print ("\t MÊS\tSALDO INICIAL\tPRESTAÇÃO\tAMORTIZAÇÃO\tJUROS\tSALDO FINAL")
print ("\t ---\t-------------\t---------\t-----------\t-----\t-----------")

print ("\t%4.i \t %12.2f \t\t\t %10.2f" % (prazo, valor_financiamento, amortizacao))
for p in range(prazo):
    while (valor_financiamento > 1):
        valor_financiamento = valor_financiamento - amortizacao # Saldo devedor
        prazo = prazo - 1 # Referência do mês
        saldo_devedor = valor_financiamento - amortizacao
        saldo_final = saldo_devedor - amortizacao
        print ("\t%4.i \t %12.2f \t\t\t %10.2f" % (prazo, valor_financiamento, amortizacao)) #% valor_financiamento)
        #print (prazo)
```

Essa questão é uma questão de financiamento imobiliário segundo o sistema SAC:

**Questão**

Construa um programa que gere uma tabela com os valores das prestações mensais de um financiamento, discriminando os valores referentes à amortização e aos juros a serem pagos até a amortização total do financiamento. Este programa deve apresentar um menu de opções e pedir as seguintes informações ao usuário: Valor financiado, Prazo (em meses) para quitação do financiamento, Taxa de juros anual (em percentual) e o Sistemática de pagamento mensal das prestações (Sistema de Amortização Constante – SAC ou Sistema PRICE - ver nota explicativas em anexo). Funcionalidades adicionais serão bem vindas!

O valor de um financiamento deve ser restituído (amortizado) ao financiador em certo período de tempo, acrescido dos juros. Amortizar significa reduzir o valor da dívida, ou seja, pagar uma parte da dívida periodicamente para que ela reduza de tamanho até a sua eliminação. Como a dívida implica em cobrança de juros, para amortiza-la é necessário que a prestação seja maior que os juros cobrados em cada período, ou seja, AMORTIZAÇÃO = PAGAMENTO – JUROS (o valor amortizado é o que sobra depois de descontados os juros). Os juros só incidem sobre o saldo devedor, onde SALDO DEVEDOR = DÍVIDA INICIAL – VALOR AMORTIZADO. As formas de amortizar financiamentos são denominados de “Sistemas de Amortização”.

Sistema de Amortização Constante (SAC): Neste sistema, o saldo devedor é reembolsado periodicamente em valores de amortização iguais. Desta forma, o valor das prestações é decrescente, já que os juros diminuem a cada prestação. O valor da amortização é calculado dividindo-se o valor do principal (valor do
financiamento) pelo número de períodos de pagamento, ou seja, de parcelas. Assim,

 Valor da amortização: AMORTIZAÇÃO = PRINCIPAL / N

 Valor dos juros no mês T: JUROST = (N - T + 1) * AMORTIZAÇÃO * TAXA

 Valor da parcela em T: PRESTAÇÃOT = AMORTIZAÇÃO + JUROST

onde: PRINCIPAL é o valor do financiamento, N é o número de meses do financiamento, T denota o
mês em questão e TAXA é a taxa de juros mensal (que deve ser obtida a partir da taxa anual).

Se alguém puder me ajudar pelo menos com a lógica. Já é um grande começo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leia o enunciado do seu próprio problema, fazendo o grandíssimo favor,

```
import os

principal = float ( input ("1. Informe o valor a ser financiado: "))
os.system("cls")
n = int ( input ("2. Informe o prazo de quitação do financiamento (em meses): "))
os.system("cls")
taxa_juros_anual = float (input ("3. Informe a taxa de juros anual (em %): ")) / 100.0
os.system("cls")
```

> Valor da amortização: AMORTIZAÇÃO = PRINCIPAL / N

```
amortizacao = principal / n
```

Uma busca por *taxa mensal a partir da taxa anual juros compostos*, no Google, devolve a seguinte fórmula,

> 1 + TAXA ANUAL = (1 + TAXA MENSAL) ^ 12 Fonte: [aqui](http://www.clubedospoupadores.com/ferramentas/como-converter-taxa-de-juros-anual-ou-mensal.html)

```
taxa_juros_mensal = pow(1.0 + taxa_juros_anual, 1.0 / 12) - 1.0;

print ("AMORTIZAÇÃO: R$ %.2f" % amortizacao)
print ("VALOR DO FINANCIAMENTO: R$ %.2f\n\n" % principal)
print ("\t FINANCIAMENTO = R$ %.2f \t MESES: %i meses \t TAXA: %i%% ano (%.f%%)" % 
    (principal, n, taxa_juros_anual, taxa_juros_mensal))
print ("\t","-"*80,"\n")
print ("\t MÊS\tSALDO INICIAL\tPRESTAÇÃO\tAMORTIZAÇÃO\t  JUROS\tSALDO FINAL")
print ("\t ---\t-------------\t---------\t-----------\t-------\t-----------")

saldo_inicial = principal
for t in range(1, n + 1):
    saldo_final = saldo_inicial - amortizacao
    juros = juros_t(t, n, amortizacao, taxa_juros_mensal)
    prestacao = amortizacao + juros

    print ("\t%4.i\t%13.2f\t%9.2f\t%11.2f\t%7.2f\t%11.2f" % 
        (t, saldo_inicial, prestacao, amortizacao, juros, saldo_final))
    saldo_inicial = saldo_final
```

> Valor dos juros no mês T: JUROST = (N - T + 1) * AMORTIZAÇÃO * TAXA

```
def juros_t(t, n, amortizacao, taxa):
      return (n - t + 1) * amortizacao * taxa
```

Comment: Marcelo, primeiramente muito obrigado pela ajuda! Ainda bem que pelo menos eu consegui compreender a lógica do programa né. Lembrando que eu ainda sou iniciante na programação e não sei muita coisa sobre python. Principalmente o professor passando questões difícieis como essa para alunos iniciantes como eu resolver. Mas desde já muito obrigado! Consegui entender o que eu não tava conseguindo.